# How to get all post except particular category without breaking the paging

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I'm trying to get all post except particular category this works fine but it cause the pagination button/link to render the same posts again on page 2, 3, 4 and so on not rendering the older post.
Here is how I am trying to exclude a particular category

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-22');?>
```

This excludes the category but prevents pagination buttons/link from showing older posts, instead it shows the same first 5 posts as on page 1.

I tried moving the category exclusion bit into the `<?php if ( have_posts('cat=-22') ) : ?>`
     line but this doesn't change anything.

I'm trying to do this on the `index.php` and `archive.php`

I've also tried excluding the category by its name and I get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would [filter `pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). Perhaps like so, though you may need to tweak the conditional a bit:

```
function wpse71508_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_main_query() ) {
        if ( is_home() || is_archive() ) {
            $query->set( 'cat', '-22' );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse71508_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

If you could clarify the *context* (rather than the *template file*) to which you want to apply this query modification, I can be more specific.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly :) I was trying to remove category B from the archive page but the `'cat=-22'` was breaking the pagination